# Time Limit Exceeding for spoj CANDYSTN

Tags: c++, time-limiting

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        long long int i,a,b,arr[10000]={0},dif,sum=0,tem=1,t;
        cin>>t;
        for(int m=0;m<t;m++)
        {
            cin>>a>>b;
            for(i=0;i<b;i++)
            {
                cin>>arr[i];
            }
            for(i=0;i<(b-1);i++)
            {
                dif=arr[i+1]-arr[i];
                sum=sum+dif;
                if(sum<=0 && tem>sum)
                {
                    tem=sum;
                }

            }
            if(a>(1-(tem)))
                cout<<1-tem<<"\n";
            else
                cout<<"-1"<<"\n";

        }
            return 0;
    }
```

https://ideone.com/vi7TVl
This is the link to my code.
I am not able to implement Dynamic Programming.

Please help.
What can i do to decrease my time.

Comment: Your code also gives the wrong result for the last test case in the sample test cases.

Comment: yup i checked.
it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This problem requires reading a lot of data so `cin` is too slow for it. You can use `scanf` instead.

Comment: What about reading into a buffer and using `cin::read()`, then extract the values from the buffer using `std::istringstream`?  The performance bottleneck is I/O, followed by converting from textual representation to internal representation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Acorrding to my experience in competitive programming, using input/output streams often causes troubles with time limit. The easiest solution in such cases is to use c-style i/o(and replacing cin with scanf is simpler than reading data to a buffer and than converting it, imho).

Comment: @user3500859 Custom i/o using getc_unlocked and putc_unlocked is even faster than scanf. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the array, it's not needed.

Use two variables, `present` and `previous`.  The `present` variable contains the value that was read in.  The `previous` variable contains the value that was previously entered.

You can eliminate 2 of the loops.

```
  cin >> a >> b;
  int previous = 0;
  int present = 0;
  cin >> present;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < b - 1; ++i)
  {
    previous = present;
    cin >> present;
    dif = present - previous;
    sum += diff;
    if ( (sum < 0) && (tem > sum))
    {
      tem = sum;
    }
  }
```

*By the way, variable names are allowed to more than 3 letters long.*

Comment: Thanks a lot 

P.S I know ..:)

Comment: I did it but still getting Time Limit Exceeding.

What to do